# How to get a String from a Future<String> in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a strange problem. I need the value of a `Future<String>` as `String` to display an image with `CachedNetworkImage`. Because I have to wait for a downloadUrl which comes from Firebase Storage I found no way to use it as normal String.

**Here is my Widget where I need the value**

```
Container(child: Obx(
  () {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: _getImage(), // Here I need the value as String
        height: Get.height,
        fit: BoxFit.cover);
  },
))
```

**And this is my `_getImage()` function**

```
Future<String> _getImage() async {
  var url = return await MyStorage().getDownloadUrl(url);
  return url;
}
```

**The `getDownloadUrl()` only returns a String with the download url from Firebase Storage**

```
Future<String> getDownloadUrl(ref) async {
    final StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(ref);
    final url = await storage.getDownloadURL();

    return url.toString();
}
```

Because I definitely have to wait for the `getDownloadUrl()` I have no chance to return the value as `String`. But I need it as `String`. Otherwise I get an error.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Try using FutureBuilder. Widget that computes future method first, and afterwards let you build your wanted widget with given value from future.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FutureBuilder` will build the UI depending on the state of the `Future`. All you have to do is check if it has the data, then build the image.

```dart
  Future<String> myFutureString() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return 'Hello';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: myFutureString(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(snapshot.data),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```